# Enumerating process id in kernel mode with EPROCESS structure

Tags: pointers, structure, kernel32

I want to enumerate all of the process id running on my system by using EPROCESS structure but the problem here is, I do not know how to access to the UniqueProcessId field in EPROCESS structure.
Now, I've got the pointer to EPROCESS structure by this function 
     PEPROCESS Process;
     PsLookupProcessByProcessId(_ProcessID,&Process);
and calculated the offset of UniqueProcessId field which is 0x0b4.
I attempted this code "*(Process+0x0b4(UniqueProcessId offset))" to get the value of UniqueProcessId field but always it brought wrong and invalid value/data.
Could anyone help me know how to access to the UniqueProcessId field?
My system is Windows7/x86. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use [PsGetProcessId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/ntddk/nf-ntddk-psgetprocessid)

Cheers,
Gabriel